# C# ExecuteQuery null value

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, null, executequery

I have some code:

```
using (OAZISDBDataContext ctx = new OAZISDBDataContext())
            {                    
                IEnumerable<DBContactDetail> details = ctx.ExecuteQuery<DBContactDetail>("exec [dbo].[zna_contact] {0}, {1}",
                    "test", "19601023",
             }
```

However I also want to be able to pass empty values to the stored procedure so it just doesn't use them.

Now with strings this is easy, I can just pass String.Empty and it will work.
However if I want to pass empty dates this is a problem.

I obviously tried:

```
using (OAZISDBDataContext ctx = new OAZISDBDataContext())
            {                    
                IEnumerable<DBContactDetail> details = ctx.ExecuteQuery<DBContactDetail>("exec [dbo].[zna_contact] {0}, {1}",
                    "test", null,
             }
```

But this doesn't' work, gives the error:

> System.Exception: A queryparameter can't be of type System.Object.

After some reading I found out that the ExecuteCommand does not support null parameters while the spec asserts that it should.

Has anybody encountered this issue and found a workaround?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending `DBNull.Value` or new `Nullable<DateTime>()` ?